# jQuery: Ajax before submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a little trouble figuring out how to do an action when submiting a form, but before it is sent. The thing is that the action tag redirects the user to a different site, and I need AJAX to send an email when I click the submit button. The user should be redirected even if AJAX fails.

I read about $.ajax() but I don't understand how to stop the form submition until jQuery gets a response. Is it done automatically?

On another thread I saw that it's recommended to use an input type "button" instead of submit.
I know that this would allow me to manuallydo a $(form).submit(); later, giving me better control, but I still strugle to fully understand the previous part.

I know the answer to this is very simple, and I'm probably running in circles over complicating myself!

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To prevent form submission until the ajax request completes, you can disable the `async` option.

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'my_url.php',
  async:false,
  .....
});
```

Comment: So when $.ajax() receives a response, the rest of the jquery code is executed? Do I have to set the success param with anything special?

Comment: No, you don't need to do anything special with the success param.  When you set `async` to false, the `$.ajax` function will not return until after it receives a response, so the rest of your code will be delayed until the request completes.

Comment: This solution was extremely easy to implement and worked wonders, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The recommendation you saw elsewhere is exactly what you need to do.

You need to cancel the submission immediately.  (by `return false`ing or by calling `e.preventDefault()`)
Then, when you get a reply from the server, you can re-submit the form in your AJAX callback.
(just make sure that you don't do the AJAX request again the second time)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the form's `onSubmit` attribute.

```
<form action="./something.php" method="post" onSubmit="someFunction();">
```

If the function returns `true` the default action takes place, otherwise the default action is prevented.